# Looking for idiomatic way to regex-process a text file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, idioms

I'm looking for idiomatic way to regex-process a text file in Ruby, and here's the best thing I've been able to come up with so far.  It removes all `"` chars:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

src_name = ARGV[0]
dest_name = ARGV[1]
File.open(src_name, "r+") { |f| 
  new_lines = f.map { |l| 
    l = l.gsub(/"/,'')
  }
  dest_file = File.new(dest_name,"w")
  new_lines.each { |l|
    dest_file.puts l
  }
}
```

There's got to be something better.  For instance:

- Why do I have to rewrite the file, shouldn't I be able to do something smarter with pipes?
- I'm doing everything line-by-line, it seems like I should be able to address the problem with input and output streams.

Comment: not ruby, but sed (if on *nix) is built for this and would eliminate the need for a ruby script `sed 's/"//g' <input >output`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eugen's answer is awesome. Here is the same thing as a "normal" script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
STDOUT << STDIN.read.gsub(/"/,'')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going for simple replacing like that, you can do it at command line like that:

```
ruby -e '$_.gsub!(/"/,"")' -i.bak -p INPUT_FILE.txt
```

It runs whatever you pass as the argument to the -e flag, replaces the content of the INPUT_FILE.txt with the result and just for safety saves a copy of the original with the .bak extension.